# How to stop a function sending data to websocket and switch to another alternately with button click

Tags: javascript, function, websocket

I feed data to websocket and send it to a server with the method below:

```
function sendData(source, images) {
    var data = {
            data_source: this.source,
            img: this.images
        };
    var Data = JSON.stringify({ type:'image', data: data });
    socket.send(Data);
}

function source1() {
    var source = camera1;
    var images = feed1;
    sendData(this.source, this.images);
}

function source2() {
    var source = camera2;
    var images = feed2;
    sendData(this.source, this.images);
}

button1.addEventListener('click', source1, false);
button2.addEventListener('click', source2, false);
```

How do I stop source1 feeding when I click on a button 2 and switch click alternately.

In my current practice when I click on a button 2 function source1 is still running. It causes the image rendered on the other end flipping (maybe not the right word, my English is not good) between two image sources. And worst, when I switching clicks between two buttons for a few times it crashed completely.

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem it is on the recipients side. Websockets runs over TCP, which has an internal buffer for buffering the streamed data being sent. No matter how you abuse the sending, they will always arrive in the correct order and un-malformed.

Comment: The code I render the image on the other end is just 'image.src = msg.data.img'. How do I remove a previous data received. Look like it's cache image, because it's stop moving. But all sources image switch so fast.

Comment: This is not right. As I detect data transfer into server, it still receives data from two sources alternately.